Telzio API unable to call via Google Appscript but working with Postman
Here's my code
function sendScheduledSMS() {
  const apiKey = [telzio_api]
  const token = [my_token]

  const number_id = [number_id]
  const recipient = [recipient_number]
  const text = 'test';

  const url = 'https://api.telzio.com/v3/conversations/sms/create-conversation';
  const payload = {
    'number_id': number_id,
    'recipient': recipient,
    'text': text
  };

  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log('SMS sent successfully: ' + result);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error sending SMS: ' + error);
  }
}

I keep getting a 403 response when it's executed via Google Appscript but when I call this via Postman I can get a 200 response. I don't know anymore if there's something wrong with my code or there are other steps I need to do in Appscript to let me call an API. Please help. Thank you.
For reference of the Telzio v3 docs
https://api.telzio.com/v3/index.html#tag/Conversations/paths/~1v3~1conversations~1sms~1create-conversation/post

When I saw your provided official document, it seems that "Content type" is application/json. And also, the status code 403 indicates that the server understood the request but refused to process it. Ref From this situation, how about the following modification?
From:
const options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  }
};

To:
const options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json', // Modified
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  }
};

Note:

This modification supposes that your token and values of payload are valid values. Please be careful about this.
I cannot test this request. So, please test the modified script. When an error occurs, please provide the detailed error message.

